# REST Service http methods

Tags: rest

As I'm new to rest services, I would like to know the difference between http methods like

```
POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, PATCH
```

as I learned these methods do different operations in rest service call like
"POST" create new record and "PUT" update the records etc.

please anyone clarify these doubts, if it is possible to use "POST"
to create records and delete records also. But what is the difference in using each of these http methods to achieve different process. How exactly that works. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can read up the available HTTP operations directly from [IANA's method registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-methods/http-methods.xhtml) and follow the links to the respective specifications. The common operations, like `POST`, `GET`, ..., are defined in [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3) while `PATCH` is defined in [RFC 5789](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789) and can be looked up there directly.

Note that RFC 7231 defined `POST` as an all-purpose tool where the semantics are defined by the implementor of the serivce, thus this operation can be used to litterally do anything or nothing. You can use it to start some processes, create, update or delete files or whatever fency stuff you need.

Answer (score 0):

Those **verbs**, in their pure form, are only used to represent an action, they don't have any actual implementation. It's up to the server to decide what happens when a request + verb(method) is received on a specific endpoint.

Just for example purposes, you can issue a `GET http://hostname/customers/1` request and the request handler on the server could actually be implemented to delete the *customer* resource with the *id* 1, of course, this is a very bad practice.

Also, as Roman mentioned, you can find those verbs definitions and usages in RFC 7231.